# Need a solution for mass Windows 10 deployment in computer charity

Tags: windows, deployment

I am a volunteer technician for a computer charity, which provides computers for distance education. Recently, demand has significantly increased and we’re struggling to keep up.

I would like to ask you for help.

We need to install Windows the most efficient way possible. Unfortunately, the hardware we work with (all old computers collected from people or companies) is very diverse, most of it is 5 to 15 years old – which means we need to support both UEFI (ideally with Secure boot enabled) and legacy BIOS. Also, while many of the computers have Windows Pro, about 25-30% have Home, so we need to be able to deploy both editions.

I’ve been researching this thoroughly, but my head hurts from all of it. I’ve tried using answer files for unattended installation, but failed. Another problem I had was getting PXE to work with UEFI machines. I’ve decided not to go that way, since everyone recommended me to use some image deploying solution. WDS looks promising, but we would need to buy an expensive Windows Server licence, so I’m trying to avoid that (however, if everything else fails, this seems to be the most straightforward and, most importantly, the best documented approach).

We need to deploy Windows with correct configuration (surveillance turned off, fast boot disabled etc.) and software (Chrome, Libreoffice, MS Teams, Eset Internet Security) to 10-15 computers at once. We want to do it over network with minimal operator input needed. We have a solid enough network infrastructure (we can invest into it more if needed) and a Xeon workstation, which we can use as a PXE server.

I have found this tutorial for creating a golden Windows 10 image and I’d like to use it in some way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PdKMiFKGQuc

Summary of requirements we have:

- Both UEFI and legacy
- Both Home and Pro editions of Windows 10
- Automatically create user account without password (and password expiration)
- Do not join / require a domain or any other enterprise stuff. These computers do not need to be administered centrally, nor will we update them using this method.
- Free (and open source), if possible. We can afford to spend a couple hundred dollars, but prefer not to.
- It would be great, if it automatically installed all updates including all available drivers, instead of us having to run Windows update and manually select all the optional driver updates.
- I would like to use NIC bonding to increase bandwidth, if possible.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There are thousands of products the chose from, because most requirements can be met by just using the unattend.xml file for your setups.

Comment: Give [Serva](https://www.vercot.com/~serva/default.html) a try.